# How do I redirect a URL in Grails to go to a specific Controller/action?

Tags: url, grails, redirect, jqgrid, mappings

So, I am running my grails application and the URL generated from the localhost is http://localhost:8888/appname/

When I enter the above link in the URL, I want it to be redirected to http://localhost:8888/appname/controller1/action1

This is my UrlMappings,

```
static mappings = {
    "/"(controller: 'controller1', view: 'action1')
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I do this, I am not getting the desired output. The URL doesn't change. But, I am getting the page desired. However, certain elements of the page don't load (For example, I have a jqGrid).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
"/"(controller: 'controller1', action: 'action1')
```

i.e in place of `view` it should be `action`

Comment: Tried that too.. But, having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`"/"(redirect: [controller: 'controller1', action: 'action1'])`

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectMappings

Comment: Tried this. But getting the following error. 

"Unable to establish controller name to dispatch for [null]. Dynamic closure invocation returned null. Check your mapping file is correct, when assigning the controller name as a request parameter it cannot be an optional token!"

Comment: Did you try the other format, `"/"(redirect: '/controller1/action1')?  Also, what version of Grails are you using?  Redirects in url mappings appear to have been introduced in Grails 2.3.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Same error. I am using 2.3.7!